# Best practise - optimal time to assign a data type to columns imported table

Tags: r

I import a csv file containing around 200 columns. Code used:

`read.csv2("t_table.txt", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)`

The data types of the different columns vary (e.g. text, numeric, date, ...).

I do not need all columns, therefore I do not assign a data type upon import of the data since  (it is handy to keep all columns in case a third party requests an additional analysis). Whenever I do use a column and the text data type does not suffice, I convert the column's data type (and store it).

I was wondering whether this is considered to be good/best practice when dealing with input tables with many columns (I suspect not...). What is advised here?

Note that I use a configuration table in which I assign properties/characteristics to the different columns. I therefore thought about doing the following: extend the configuration table with a data type column (which would link/assign a data type to every column) and write a script that assigns the data type to each and every column. Any thoughts on this approach?

Note: I consider working with configuration tables easy, because they reduce the amount of code, increase the transparency of the code and often reduce changes to the code to changes to a configuration table.

Comment: I would go for your own solution of extending your configuration table.

Comment: Have you considered transferring the data to a database system that will control the data types for you?

Comment: Have a look at the `readr` library. It allows you to specifiy the column types with great details but also allows you to use the automatic type inferrer which is really good. You can also go in-between, and for example use automatic typing for all columns except those you explictly override. It is quite versatile. I am in the same situation and I store the "cols" objects (created with `readr::cols`) which contains the column specifications. This `cols` object can be passed to any `readr` functions (like `read_csv2` -- note the underscore) to read the file correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although some of the approaches suggested might be better, I came up with an approach that works well for me and does not require a lot of work to set it up or a lot of maintenance; e.g. configuration tables specifying the data type of every field would have been a lot of work to set up and some work to maintain.

My approach consists of importing the data as `data.table` using `fread`:

```
t_input_table         = fread(paste(locationConfig, "t_input_table.csv", sep="/"), 
                          header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

`fread` manages to distinguish between integer, numeric and character fields well. Dates are, in my case, considered as text. All date fields headers', however, contain the string '_date'. I then look for these fields and ensure that they are assigned a date type:

```
dateColumns = grep("_date$", colnames(t_input_table))
t_input_table[ , (dateColumns) := lapply(.SD, as.Date, format="%d/%m/%Y"), .SDcols = dateColumns]
```